# How to properly manage specific Safari inputs behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari

I build an app in React. There is a signup form, where I enter email, password and other information.

All works as expected in Chrome, but it's kinda weird in Safari. When I begin entering something into an input, it doesn't put anything in that field, but shows this for email:

[image: email input]

How do I make it work just as it should in a regular scenario?

1. onChange => changeField(value) via redux dispatch
2. save in store
3. rerender with new value

Even more weirdness is in the inspector which shows value attribute changing while typing, but the input is still empty visually.

[image: value not visualized in DOM]

Comment: Can you please provide more info? Some code to begin with and perhaps any errors you may be getting.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big debate about `onChange` on other browsers, such as IE or Safari (depending on the version).

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/554
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7027

And so on...

What I suggest is to consider `onInput` in cases where the `onChange` fails to do what you expect due to time issues